UITextView weird behavior
I just wrote this SwiftUI or UiKit Editor with basic line numbers. I works pretty well, but has a major flaw. Whenever the variable behind the text value changes the editor messes up. This is pretty difficult to explain so I am going to give a quick example.
Let's say I have an array of data called files. ( I can't use strings sadly )
In order to use my editor with this array of data I wrote a simple binding.
Here:
let binding = Binding(
    get: {
        String(data: files[i].content, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
    },
    set: {
        files[i].content = $0.data(using: .utf8) ?? Data()
    }
)
                        
CodeEditor(text: binding)

In the code above 'i' is just he value that's responsible of which file is selected in the array. For example if 'i' is 0 then the fist data object is selected and etc...
Now for the actually problem. If 'i' changes and then actual changes get made via the editor it will just save them to whatever it wants to and just overrides everything. I tested the binding previously with SwiftUI's regular TextEditor and everything worked just fine.
Here is CodeEditor.swift:
import SwiftUI

struct CodeEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    var colorScheme: ColorScheme = .dark
    var showLineNumbers: Bool = true
    
    var textView = LineNumberedTextView()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LineNumberedTextView {
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.autocorrectionType = .no
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .none
        textView.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        textView.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineNumberedTextView, context: Context) {
        // Prevent redundant updates
        if uiView.text != text {
            uiView.text = text
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent: CodeEditor
        
        init(_ parent: CodeEditor) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            // Update the binding only if the text has actually changed
            if self.parent.text != textView.text {
                self.parent.text = textView.text
            }
        }
        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            self.parent.textView.currentLines = textView.text.lineNumbersForRange(textView.selectedRange) ?? []
            self.parent.textView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}

func findRegex(pattern: String, text: String) -> [NSRange] {
    
    var result: [NSRange] = []
    
    if let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .caseInsensitive) {
        let matches = regex.matches(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.count))
        for match in matches {
            result.append(match.range)
        }
    }
    
    return result
}

extension String {
    func lineNumbersForRange(_ range: NSRange) -> [Int]? {
        guard
            let startIndex = self.index(self.startIndex, offsetBy: range.location, limitedBy: self.endIndex),
            let endIndex = self.index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.length, limitedBy: self.endIndex)
        else {
            return nil
        }
        
        let substring = self[startIndex..<endIndex]
        var lineNumbers: [Int] = []
        
        // Find the lines within the range
        let linesInRange = substring.components(separatedBy: .newlines)
        
        // Calculate the number of newline characters before the start index
        let lineBreaksBeforeStartIndex = self[..<startIndex].components(separatedBy: .newlines).count - 1
        
        // Iterate over each line within the range
        for (index, _) in linesInRange.enumerated() {
            // Calculate the line number for each line within the range
            let lineNumber = lineBreaksBeforeStartIndex + index + 1
            lineNumbers.append(lineNumber)
        }
        
        return lineNumbers
    }
}


class LineNumberedTextView: UITextView {
    let lineNumberGutterWidth: CGFloat = 50
    var currentLines: [Int] = []
    var showLineNumbers: Bool = true
    var colorScheme: ColorScheme = .light
    
    // This is the function which draws the line numbers
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        // Set the alignment, color, font and size for the line numbers
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
        
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .ultraLight),
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: colorScheme == .light ? UIColor(white: 0.8, alpha: 1) : UIColor(white: 0.2, alpha: 1)
        ]
        let attributes_active: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .ultraLight),
            .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
            .foregroundColor: colorScheme == .light ? UIColor.black : UIColor.white
        ]
        
        // The editor needs these values in order to keep track if a line has wrapped or not.
        var lineNum = 1
        var lineRect = CGRect.zero
        let full = NSRange(location: 0, length: self.textStorage.length)
        var isWrapped = false
        
        // Enumerate, aka. go over each single ones of the lines
        layoutManager.enumerateLineFragments(forGlyphRange: full) { (rect, usedRect, textContainer, glyphRange, stop) in

            // This code checks whether a line is inside the full fragment os wraps around.
            let charRange: NSRange = self.layoutManager.glyphRange(forCharacterRange: glyphRange, actualCharacterRange: nil)
            let paraRange: NSRange? = (self.textStorage.string as NSString?)?.paragraphRange(for: charRange)
            
            let wrapped = charRange.location == paraRange?.location
            
            // Only if the line did **not** wrap, it draws the line number.
            if wrapped {
                lineRect = CGRect(x: 8, y: rect.origin.y + self.textContainerInset.top, width: self.lineNumberGutterWidth, height: rect.height)
                let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? attributes_active : attributes)
                attributedString.draw(in: lineRect)
                lineNum += 1
            }
            isWrapped = !wrapped
        }
        
        // Handle the special case where the text is empty, so there is at least one number at all times.
        if self.textStorage.string.isEmpty {
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? attributes_active : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(at: CGPoint(x: 8, y: self.textContainerInset.top))
        }
        
        // Another special case where the last line ends with a newline, because for some reason the editor doesn't count that as a new fragment.
        if self.textStorage.string.hasSuffix("\n") {
            let rect = lineRect.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: isWrapped ? (lineRect.height * 2) : lineRect.height)
            let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "\(lineNum)", attributes: self.currentLines.contains(lineNum) ? attributes_active : attributes)
            attributedString.draw(in: rect)
        }
    }
    
    // This resets and layouts everything / sets the line number padding
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: textContainerInset.top, left: lineNumberGutterWidth, bottom: textContainerInset.bottom, right: textContainerInset.right)
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    

    // The text changed so this updates the line numbers.
    override var text: String! {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
}


Make needs to init it eg
func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LineNumberedTextView {
    let view = LineNumberedTextView()
    ...

Also you can't pass self to the coordinator cause it will be immediately out of date
func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

Full code as requested:
struct CodeEditor: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var text: String
    let colorScheme: ColorScheme = .dark
    let showLineNumbers: Bool = true
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> LineNumberedTextView {
        let textView = LineNumberedTextView()
        textView.isEditable = true
        textView.delegate = context.coordinator
        textView.autocorrectionType = .no
        textView.autocapitalizationType = .none
        textView.keyboardType = .asciiCapable
        textView.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        textView.textContainer.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        return textView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: LineNumberedTextView, context: Context) {

        context.coordinator.textDidChange = nil
        
        if uiView.text != text {
            uiView.text = text
        }
        if uiView.colorScheme != colorScheme {
           uiView.colorScheme = colorScheme
        }
        if uiView.showLineNumbers != showLineNumbers {
            uiView.showLineNumbers = showLineNumbers
        }
        
        context.coordinator.textDidChange = { newText in
            text = newText
        }

    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator()
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        
        var textDidChange: ((String) -> ())? = nil

        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textDidChange?(textView.text)
        }

        func textViewDidChangeSelection(_ textView: UITextView) {
            textView.currentLines = textView.text.lineNumbersForRange(textView.selectedRange) ?? []
            textView.setNeedsLayout()
        }
    }
}


Hi Malhal, thanks for your answer. But I am very new to UIKit and barely got the first one working, so could you please edit your answer to include the full code and then I will accept it. Thanks in advance.

Sure, full code added

This just made my day better because the thing I was working on for like 3 weeks now finally runs without bugs. Bless you.
